# How to disable VS Code minimap in Windowed mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I did the following in Visual Studio Code:

1. settings.json => "editor.minimap.enabled": true
2. Open 2ed files side by side (windowed mode)
3. Minimap exists in both windows

This takes up too much room, but I still want to use the Minimap when I'm editing a single file in a single window. Is there a way to have the Minimap enabled for a single file, but disabled in side-by-side "Windowed" mode?

Comment: this is avaiable in newest vscode

Comment: {
    "key": "cmd+l",
    "command": "editor.action.toggleMinimap"
  },

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Toggle minimap command has been added since vscode 1.16. Hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and select `View: Toggle Minimap`.

Comment: for windows user View -> Show Minimap button toggle

Comment: what is the shortcut for it? frequent use needed

Comment: @Martian2049 you can add your own keybind

Comment: {
    "key": "cmd+l",
    "command": "editor.action.toggleMinimap"
  },

Answer (score 43):

There is no way to do this in VS Code. Currently there is only the `"editor.minimap.enabled": false` setting which can be true or false and either always enables the minimap or always disables it.

Unfortunately, as shown in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21754), there is also no "toggleMinimap" command to assign to keybindings.

You might find [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler) useful, though, as it can be used to create a toggle minimap command:

settings:

```
"settings.cycle": [
    {
        "setting": "editor.minimap.enabled"
    }
]
```

keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "settings.cycle.workbench.colorTheme",
    "when": ""
}
```

Comment: Put that code where? You can't just post things without any context.

Comment: VS Code has a `settings.json` file for user or workspace settings. If anybody tells you to change a "setting" in VS Code, they mean to edit that file. You can access the settings file via the command palette or the toolbar

Answer (score 21):

Simplest way is go to:
`View` **->** `Toggle Minimap`

**Update:**

In newer versions:
`View` **->** `Show Minimap`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but King Julien already answered this. So your answer is duplicate. But I vote up anyway because you show me how to do it by mouse instead of keyboard.

Comment: Welcome. His answer is correct, I'm just telling an alternate way to command palette as you stated. :)

Comment: In 1.40.1 this is called `Show Minimap` instead of `Toggle Minimap`

Answer (score 10):

To remove/disable/hide VS Code Minimap, 
Go to the **View** tab and **uncheck** this: `View > Show Minimap`

[image: remove/disable/hide VS Code Minimap]

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2) type in "View: minimap"
3) right click and add a key binding.
I like to use `ctrl+m` ("m" for minimap)

If there are existing key bindings, you can use another one, or click the existing one(s) listed, then right click them and remove the binding before repeating steps 2 and 3 above.

Answer (score 0):

New option available,
View-> Show minimap (uncheck)

Answer (score 0):

In **Visual Studio Code** **Version 1.41.1**. Go to

> `Files` >> `Preferences` >> `Settings`

Select

> `Text Editor` >> `Minimap` >> Uncheck `Enabled` checkbox

Answer (score -1):

I didnt find "minimap", instead I found:

[Options]>>[Text Editor]>>[All Languages]>>[Scroll Bars]>>Behavior>>"Use map mode for vertical scroll bar"

[I am not able to embed image yet, check link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfQgK.png)