# Question Visual Studio Code IDE issue: how to hide the "special" code navigation vertical bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio Code (vscode) in the last weeks, so I am pretty newbie to it. It has some nice features, but there are some catches and surprises too. Right now, I want to hide a column where we can navigate the current source being edited, in a kind of scroll bar, but with a code thumbnail look. I have taken a screenshot to show you what I mean. It is highlighted in red:

https://imgbox.com/cMMS4rgJ

I searched the menus, tested most of it, but I could not find this. And clicking, right clicking and double clicking in the actual scroll thing does not do anything either.

While composing this question, [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code) was suggested to me. It has nothing to do with my problem.

My VSC version:

```
Versão: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Data: 2021-12-15T09:39:46.686Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.10.0-8-amd64
```

So, can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable VS Code minimap in Windowed mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982787/how-to-disable-vs-code-minimap-in-windowed-mode)

Comment: Yes, but in a different way. And in this other thread, the VSC version is only mentioned indirectly, and this feature has changed over the time. So, i would prefer to see my question and its current answer and comments as a best result for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl(cmd)+shift+p  >   vtmi

Comment: So, my problem could be thought as, basically, not knowing the name of that thing: minimap. Thank you!

Comment: I took sometime to figure out a free keyboard shortcut, and something that makes sense, but i eventually chose one that should be easy to remember: CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F12

Comment: Why F12? Because F12, in browsers, shows Developer Tools! (:   In very long code files, i may want to use minimap. But most of the time, i prefer that space empty, free to have more screen space for other things.

Comment: Is the meaning of "vtmi" "**V**irtual **T**oogle **MI**nimap" ?

Comment: @Dedec0 Why don't you try the key combo in the answer, then you know what `vtmi` means

Comment: @rioV8, I used the short cut before everything! What it does is to open a text box to search box to write the names of settings (it does not search for a setting if i use a shortcut while the search field is on focus, i tried this). Typing "vtmi" magically brings the setting "Ver: Ativar/Desativar Minimapa", which is written in portuguese. So... your "question" does not make me go anywhere new.

Comment: do you expect us to name a feature in all the i18n languages supported by VSC, set your language to English and find out what is suggested, find the key binding, switch back and use the key binding dialog to find the command in your language

Comment: No, @rioV8. I said it in my language to show you that i find the correct setting, though its name does not have the letters "vtmi" in it, as the english name has. And this setting did not have any shortcut by default. This is why i tried several things, before finding the one i decided to keep for it.